# How can I modify this code to insert random text into the console and it reverses it for me?

Tags: java, reverse

I'm very new to Programming and I've tried to use Integer.parseInt(args[0]); but it says that int cannot be converted to a String.

```
public class Reverse {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s = "reverse this";
 
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the connection between your question and the code you've posted.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry for my bad English, what I've tried to say is, that I want to insert my own text into the console so it reverses it for me. I've done it with Integer.parseInt(args[0]) recently on a different program, but this time it doesn't work because it`s a String. Hope it helps to understand

Comment: What you get is an array of String so `String s = args[0];` should do. Maybe best to first test that the array is not empty by checking `args.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mechanism to input text from a source e.g. keyboard or command-line etc. Given below are some examples:

**From keyboard:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a text: ");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a text: Hello World
dlroW olleH
```

**From command-line:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            for (int i = args[0].length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(args[0].charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to run it as `java Main "Hello World"` where `"Hello World"` is the command-line argument.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this suggestion Sir, is there a method for this without using the scanner?

Comment: @INVICTUS - The second option in the answer does not require a `Scanner`. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: I see now, I can't thank you enough Sir! I'm new to this website and don't have enough reputation to give you anything. It works now, if I can do anything let me know. Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: Alright, I checked your Answer since everything works now :)

Comment: @INVICTUS - Wish you success!